# ¿Qué significa "regalar" en Colombia?

Tags: definiciones, colombia

El día de hoy recibí este email de una persona de Bogotá, Colombia:

> Buenas tardes, la presenté es para solicitar  una cotización formal 
>   de una sillas tipo secretarial con brazos me gustaría por favor me
>   regalaran  las mas económicas ya que es para una de nuestras obras
>   agradezco su pronta respuesta

¿A qué se refiere con regalar? ¿tiene otra definición en Colombia? ¿acaso quiere que le regale las sillas? me parece ilógico

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Regalar" in Colombia sometimes has the meaning "give" or "sell".

It is common in a bar to say:

> - ¿Me regala una copa de vino?

So the sentence

> "me gustaría por favor me regalaran las mas económicas"

then would mean

> "I would like you to sell me the cheapest"

Find the reference from [Bogotalogo](https://www.scribd.com/doc/94635822/Bogotalogo-Version-Digital), a website with an explanation of certain words used in Bogotá:

http://www.bogotalogo.com/wiki/index.php?title=Regalar

> Extraña expresión que acaso permite entrever el carácter mendicante y proclive a solicitar dádivas gratuitas de parte del colombiano, aunque la intención sea la de comprar. De cuño reciente, la expresión ‘regalar’ ha ido suplantando al más contundente y real ‘vender’, y se usa indistintamente en tal sentido.

---

By the way there are some mistakes that I felt like checking:

> Buenas tardes, la <strike>presenté</strike> **presente** es para solicitar  una cotización formal 
>   de una sillas tipo secretarial con brazos **one stop, please** me gustaría por favor me
>   regalaran  las <strike>mas</strike> **más** económicas ya que es para una de nuestras obras **and another dot**
>   agradezco su pronta respuesta

Comment: +1 In this case, the only definition that makes sense to me is "to sell".

Comment: Yes this is true. I am colombian. Pretty funny though I had never really thought about it.

Answer (score 6):

It is an expression used to ask for something. In Colombia I use it a lot when I want to ask for something, but I don't want to seem demanding. For example, if I want to ask someone to call me at 6 pm, but I'm not giving an order, I say:

> Regálame una llamada a las 6 pm

I can change  the expression  and say:

> Por favor llámame a las 6 pm

In a market I can say: "Regálame una Coca Cola", but I am going to pay for this.

Answer (score 6):

La expresión "regalar" es muy difundida en Colombia (por mi experiencia más que todo en Bogotá) y equivale a pedir el favor o hacer una amable solicitud de un producto o servicio que (obviamente) será pagado, sin implicar una donación o regalo literalmente.

En este contexto el significado sería:
**por favor elaborar la cotización con las sillas más económicas.**

*Extra:* la redacción de la persona es un tanto confusa, pienso que realmente quiso escribir algo así: me gustaría que por favor me regalaran **una cotización** con las **sillas** más económicas.

---

the word "regalar" (to make a gift) is very popular in Colombia (mainly Bogota) and means to ask the favor or make a formal request of a product / service tht will be (obviously) paid, without implying an actual gift or donation.

In this context it would be:
**please give me a quote with the most inexpensive chairs**.

Answer (score 2):

*Regalar* en Colombia es un modismo, una forma cariñosa/formal de solicitar algo:

- En una tienda: - Buenas tardes, me regala una gaseosa.
- En una oficina: - Buenas tardes, me podrias regalar la dirección.

La puedes usar en lugares tanto formales como informales sin generar ninguna ambiguedad y demuestras dominio del lenguaje, lo cual es muy importante en Colombia.

Comment: Pregunta desde España, entonces cuando se quiere regalar algo de verdad, en el sentido de 'darlo gratis', ¿cómo se anuncia o se pide?